# Webpack compilation hash in client code

Tags: angular, webpack

## Question

I am trying to get the compilation hash as variable in Angular client code. My initial idea was to use the *ExtendedAPIPlugin* plugin via *DefinePlugin*. The Webpack plugins docs state that

*ExtendedAPIPlugin -> Adds useful free vars to the bundle.*

`__webpack_hash__` *The hash of the compilation available as free var.*

*webpack.config.js*

```
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ExtendedAPIPlugin(),
        ...
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env),
                'DEP_HASH': JSON.stringify(__webpack_hash__) // ???
            }
        })
      ]
```

*client code*

```
process.env.DEP_HASH
```

Yet the webpack build complains with:

```
ReferenceError: __webpack_hash__ is not defined
```

So where and how can this `__webpack_hash__` variable be used?

Webpack version: 3.10.0

## Solution

```
declare var __webpack_hash__: any;

export class SomeClass {
   ...
   private someFunction(): void {
      let hash = __webpack_hash__(); // Not AOT
      let hash = __webpack_hash__;   // AOT 
   } 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it directly in your application code:

**view.js**

`class SomeView {
    constructor() {
        this.hash = __webpack_hash__;
    }
}`

If you are using Typescript, you need to define `__webpack_hash__` as global variable. I guess this would do it:

`declare var __webpack_hash__: string;`

Comment: I am afraid it will not compile like that `TS2304: Cannot find name '__webpack_hash__'.`

Comment: So easy! Thanks! Just had to declare the type as function: `declare var __webpack_hash__: Function;`

Answer (score 1):

Add the `@types/webpack-env` package to as a dev dependency, you can see it [declares this variable here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4d694c49ee52b64619980d8a9336ba88d16622a2/types/webpack-env/index.d.ts#L305). And of course the benefit is that it isn't the only type you need; even if you don't use other `__webpack_*` values in your code it also gives a better (for Webpack) type of `require`, `module` and `process`. Also see https://github.com/ZSkycat/how-to-use-types-webpack-env if you want to use `@types/node` as well.