# how can i use webpack hash in html title?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

i am fresh for webpack, my webpack.config.js:

```js
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: true,
        templateParameters:{title: '[name].[contenthash]' },
        inject: true,
    }), 
],
```

in my index.ejs:

```
<title><%= title %></title>
```

but in my out/index.html, the title is only:

```
<title>[name].[contenthash]</title>
```

expect :

```
 <title>app.7472b25c2ed347463dbc</title>
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack compilation hash in client code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608397/webpack-compilation-hash-in-client-code)

Comment: thank you, but i have find it, so that question in not clear enough...

Answer (score 1):

#### 2020-11-13 update

final, i find can use global var : **webpack_hash**  like this:

```html
    <title><%=  'hash'+__webpack_hash__  %></title>
```

we can straightly use it in index.ejs, need not do anything in webpack.config.js

#### init edition

webpack.config.js:

```js
plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            // 1. title is the parameter, you can use in ejs template
            templateParameters:{
                title: JSON.stringify(someting: 'something'),
            },
        }), 


        //2. BUILT_AT is a parameter too. can use it.
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            BUILT_AT: webpack.DefinePlugin.runtimeValue(Date.now,"some"),

        }),

        //3. for webpack5, you can use global variable: __webpack_hash__
        //new webpack.ExtendedAPIPlugin()
    ],
    //4. this is not variable, this is module, so use 'import tt' to use it.
    externals: { 
        'ex_title': JSON.stringify({
            tt: 'eitentitle',
        })
    },
```

Comment: why this value `__webpack_hash__` never change? should it change when source code changed?

Comment: it will change, after everytime you build it